# Shebang for psql

Tags: postgresql, shebang, psql

I'm trying to write PostgreSQL script(s) but having a problem with shebang line

```
#! /usr/bin/psql [ psql_args_here ] -f

select now();
```

This gives me error as if I just entered `psql` without any arguments in command line. How do I do it right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that psql don't skip the first line of the file.

You could try

```
#! /bin/sh
exec sh -c "tail -n +3 $0 | psql -f -"

select now();
```

or simply

```
#! /bin/sh
psql << E_O_SQL

select now();

E_O_SQL
```

Comment: I much prefer the second one.  Its more explicit.

Answer (score 8):

There is a even better solution. The first line should be:

```
--() { :; }; exec psql -f "$0"
```

It works as a regular shebang #!

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang#PostgreSQL

Comment: The explanation of why it works is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/488070/41086 @Kusalananda